# Why this phrase is right: The hardened professional smuggler?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Why this phrase is right: The hardened professional smuggler?

I think because hardened = professional, so it is weird to see the phrase: the hardened professional smuggler.

But I know that phrase is right, can you tell me why is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardened and professional don't exactly have the same meanings.

> ## [Hardened](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hardened)
>
> used to describe someone who has had a lot of bad experiences and as a result no longer gets upset or shocked
>
> no longer likely to change a bad way of life or feel sorry about it
>
> ## [Professional](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/professional)
>
> used to describe someone who does a job that people usually do as a hobby
>
> having the type of job that is respected because it involves a high level of education and training

Anyways, it's not grammatically wrong to describe something with two similar-meaning adjectives.